# Android SDK Manager installed only API 20

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk

I downloaded android SDK from developer.android.com.

I clicked on Android SDK Manager link in eclipse. But I see only API 20 is installed. I don't find other APIs.

This is the screenshot 
  [image]

Can anyone please tell me how can I install other APIs.

Unchecked the filter "installed". But still I am not able to see other APIs
 This is the screenshot of it
 [image]

This is the information shown in the log window
 [image]
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: click on the cat icon right of stop sign in right bottom of window and see logs.

Comment: Is there any network issue?

Comment: There is no network issue.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1 ] Open the SDK Manager-->Tools-->Manage Add-on Sites-->User Defined Sites

[image]

2 ] Choose New

Use this URL "http://developer.lge.com/sdk/android/repository.xml"

Comment: Well. Tried this. But still I can see only API 20 installing. Any way thanks for the answer.